# 2D game board for android

Tags: 2d, game-design

I am trying my hand at android game development. I want to start with a simple 2D board game. What is the best way to draw a game board like the one in the image attacked below. The blue circles are points where the players can place objects.

[image]

Comment: Do you ask for a technology (canvas, OpenGL...) or a way to store and render it?

Comment: The most optimum way to store and render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a graph.

A graph is a set of connected nodes. In your case each node should have a position (vector), and an ID.

Outside the grapg you should store the connections. E.g. in your gfaph there are 5 nodes with the position (0;0), (0;1), (1;0), (1;1) and (0.5,0.5) and the IDs 0, 1 2, 3, and 4 respectively. Then your connection set would be

```
0-1, 0-3, 0-4, 1-4, 3-4, 2-1, 2-3, 2-5
```

Make sure they aren't duplicated.

You take every connection, get each IDs and their corresponding nodes, and using their positions, you draw a line.

Comment: [NOTE] Might come handy to some people. 

To store the connections of nodes, look at adjacency matrix and/or list